# Robocopy from Process sometimes Gives Access Denied, Not in BAtch File

Tags: c#, robocopy

We're running a Robocopy through a Process, so we can look at the log file after the Robocopy command fails. Sometimes, the Robocopy will give Access Denied. It's very inconsistent when the Access Denied happens. Running using an admin acct. Here's the code ...

```
            using (Process p = new Process())
            {
                Globals.lastCommand = string.Format("/C ROBOCOPY \"{0}\" \"{1}\" /MIR /J /LOG+:\"{2}\" /R:1 /W:10 /XF {3}", source, destination, Globals.tempLog, "*.bak");
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = Globals.lastCommand;
                p.StartInfo.Domain = "++++++++";
                p.StartInfo.UserName = "+++++++";
                string password = "++++++++";
                for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
                    ssPwd.AppendChar(password[x]);
                p.StartInfo.Password = ssPwd;
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = source;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
            }
```

Here's the error we're getting:

```
                   2    \\MAD2014\SYNC\017 Alliance\004 Sebree Mining\917-5026\(0016) MA 10\DMP\MPA03\ARCHIVE\9175026_MA10_042914\
                   2    \\MAD2014\SYNC\017 Alliance\004 Sebree Mining\917-5026\(0016) MA 10\DMP\MPA03\ARCHIVE\9175026_MI10_110213\
                   6    \\MAD2014\SYNC\017 Alliance\004 Sebree Mining\917-5026\(0016) MA 10\DMP\MPA03\ARCHIVE\9175026_MI10_110213\SHP_FILES_9175026_MI10\
                   0    \\MAD2014\SYNC\017 Alliance\004 Sebree Mining\917-5026\(0016) MA 10\DMP\MPA03\COLLECTION\
                  12    \\MAD2014\SYNC\017 Alliance\004 Sebree Mining\917-5026\(0016) MA 10\DMP\MPA03\COLLECTION\Correspondence\
```

2014/07/27 20:31:49 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \lex2014\projects\017 Alliance\004 Sebree Mining\917-5026(0016) MA 10\DMP\MPA03\COLLECTION\Correspondence\
Access is denied.

Waiting 10 seconds... Retrying...
2014/07/27 20:31:59 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \lex2014\projects\017 Alliance\004 Sebree Mining\917-5026(0016) MA 10\DMP\MPA03\COLLECTION\Correspondence\
Access is denied.

ERROR: RETRY LIMIT EXCEEDED.

```
                   6    \\MAD2014\SYNC\017 Alliance\004 Sebree Mining\917-5026\(0016) MA 10\DMP\MPA03\COLLECTION\ITEM_08\
                   5    \\MAD2014\SYNC\017 Alliance\004 Sebree Mining\917-5026\(0016) MA 10\DMP\MPA03\COLLECTION\ITEM_09\
```

Notice how it continues. Also, if the same Robocopy is run in a batch file, no errors. Also, we're copying from one server to the other.

Comment: Are you sure the files are not in use when you copy them? from Wikipedia "Robocopy will not copy open files. Any process may open files for exclusive read access by withholding the FILE_SHARE_READ[4] flag during opening. Even robocopy's Backup mode will not touch those files."

Comment: Pretty sure. The process runs at night when everyone has gone home. I'm the first one in every morning when I run the robocopy commands that had errors.